# Ruby map to Pair string elements in an array to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array such as

```
['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

I'm looking to create an array of each sequential pair

```
[['a','b'], ['c','d'], ['e','f']]
```

I know this is a simple question, but I am not sure how to phrase it to search for the answer and I've been searching for a while. Please point me in the right direction to an older answer and my apologies for the newbieness of the question.

Comment: `arr.each_slice(2).entries`

Answer (score 6):

```
%w[a b c d e f].each_slice(2).to_a
#=> [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]
```

Note: in most cases, you won't need to convert the result to an array. [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) is an iterator method like `#each`, you can pass it a block or if you don't, it will return an [`Enumerator`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html), which is [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) and supports pretty much all the methods you would want from an [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html).